# How to get the last Wednesday of every month since 2016?

Tags: python, pendulum

Since I want to get the last Wendnesday of every month, use pendulum.parse but sometimes 4 is last week or 5 is last week. How to get easily the day is last Wendnesday of month or not?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYnv2.png)

Comment: _"How to get easily the day is last Wendnesday of month or not?"_ Check if `mydate + 7 days` is in the same month?

Comment: Thanks for ur great idea

Answer (score -1):

You can use [the calendar module from the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.weekday) and compute all dates

> calendar.weekday(year, month, day) Returns the day of the week (0 is
> Monday) for year (1970–…), month (1–12), day (1–31).

As a helper, you can also use from the same module

> calendar.monthrange(year, month) Returns weekday of first day of the
> month and number of days in month, for the specified year and month.

Comment: ![image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/54921730/122260140-e0ebb400-cf0d-11eb-9e3f-c589c6558a3a.png) Uhm..My Question is lame. I wanna know this Wendnes day is last or not, Thank you for ur Answer. I have to think more :)